# Combine two arrays and store into a new array in C#

Tags: c#

How to merge two arrays into new one in c#. Also how to print all values of an array in c#

```
  string[] arrA = {"1", "2"};
  string[] arrB = {"3", "4"};
  var totalLen = arrA.length + arrB.length;
  
  string[] newArr = new string[totalLen];
  
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < totalLen; i++) {
      if(i < 2){
      newArr[i] = arrA[i];
      }else{
      newArr[i] = arrB[i];
      }
  }
  
  Console.WriteLine(newData[4]);
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine:

```
var arrC = arrA.Concat(arrB).ToArray();
```

Print:

```
Array.ForEach(arrC, Console.WriteLine);
```